# Add Simple PowerShell command to Batch File

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to add a couple simple PowerShell commands to a batch file.  My preference is to keep the batch file self-contained vs calling an external .ps1 file.

Task:

Remove `&` char from filenames in a specific folder structure.

The following PowerShell commands work from the command line:

```
cd c:\Media\Downloads
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*&*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '&','testing' }"
```

Here's what I attempted to add to my Batch file, without success:

```
 %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& cd c:\Media\Downloads"
 %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -command "& Get-ChildItem -Filter '*&*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '&','testing' }"
```

Can anyone provide some advice, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
powershell -c "Get-ChildItem 'c:\Media\Downloads' -Filter '*&*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace '&','testing' }"
```

- specify the path in [Get-ChildItem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx)
- no need to specify the full path to powershell

Comment: Thanks, @wOxxOm.  Tried this line:  powershell.exe -Command -c "Get-ChildItem 'c:\Media\Downloads' -Filter '*AA*' -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'AA','testing' }", but not seeing the replacement.  Permissions issue?

Comment: @MarkPelletier Does `"Get-ChildItem 'c:\Media\Downloads' -Filter 'AA' -Recurse` return anything? Your filter has no wildcards

Comment: At command line, yes.  I see results.  From within Batch file, no result.  (fixed the wildcard on my filter)

Comment: @MarkPelletier, `-command -c` is wrong, just leave one thing. The posted code in my answer works inside a batch file here. There might be something wrong in the other code.

Comment: My test batch file only has a single line (removed extra "-command").  I see the command window open, the PS line appears, but no result, no errors.  Odd.

Comment: I tried replacing "AA" vs "&" - same lack of result.  Works from command line, just not from Batch file.

Comment: And now it's working.  Odd.  Maybe I need more coffee??